# Want same desktop div division in case of mobile phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Following bootstrap code is working fine in case of desktop, i want to design the same div division or same look & feel in case of mobile phone.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-1">.col-lg-1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: use col-xs-1 with col-lg-1

Comment: Needing same width as col-lg-1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `col-<size>-<num>` sibling classes that you want to apply.
For example if you want the grid to keep same division up to the smallest sizes, use the `col-xs-<num>` class. If you want medium devices such as tablets but not smaller use `col-md-<num>`. The division holds from the specified size to larger sizes.

You can read more about this here: [Grid Options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options)

In your case, simply replace the `col-lg-1` class with `col-xs-1` as suggested.